# Hiding Toolbar when Scrolling a RecyclerView in nested Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, scroll, hide, android-toolbar

**EDIT 2;** This part of the code was OK. Check my answer for this, you might have a similar issue and I hope this solves your issue.

---

I've been checking a lot of posts with similar issues; they got me close, but I'm not able to make it right. I have a `MainActivity`, that hosts a `Fragment` loaded in the `FrameLayout` (**id:** `fragment_container`).
I want to hide the `Toolbar` when scrolling, but this only happens when I scroll the `NavigationDrawer`. When I scroll the `RecyclerView`, the `Toolbar` doesn't hide.

The `Fragment` contains a `ViewPager`, and each `ViewPagerFragment` has a `RecyclerView`.

I tried a lot of alternatives and this is the one that is closest to what I intend.

**What I want to do:**

- hide toolbar when scrolling recycler view

**What's going on right now:**

http://gifmaker.cc/PlayGIFAnimation.php?folder=2016080211dGOklkBglH6HPrbVKq2rLE&file=output_lp5KmP.gif

**My current main_activity layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:elevation="16dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/login_button"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_account_circle_white_24dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/favourites_button"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/favourite_button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bookmarked_button"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bookmarked_button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/history_button"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_history_white_24dp" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/menu" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>


<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_pressed"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/favourite_button"
    app:fabSize="mini"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/fragment_container"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />
```

EDIT; for some reason the CoordinatorLayout is not being displayed in the code I just posted. Everything is surrounded with a CoordinatorLayout!

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

Previous Code goes here.

```
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was inside the `Fragment`. I had this line that was killing the effect:

```
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

I removed it and now it works great. I've been dealing with this for so long, wish I got it earlier. Hope this helps someone out there.